# Why is there showing a 'None' in the Output?

Tags: python, function, nonetype

My programm shell show a grid and my programm has a lot of functions which calling each other. My Problem is that there are 3 Nones showing in my output. I can imagine it's because in the bracket after funtionname is written no argument in it instead of do_twice and do_fourth. But i don't need a argument because I have written a function which execute the function do_quater in the end. So I don't know if i should declare in my function a variable to hint the None.

```
def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()


def do_fourth(f):
    do_twice(f)
    do_twice(f)

def do_row():
    print '+----',
    print '+'



def do_worms():
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'


def do_wormsr():
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'

def do_row():
    print '+----',
    print '+'

def do_worms():
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'
    print '|    |'


def do_wormsr():
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'
    print      '|    |'


def do_row():
    print '+----',
    print '+'

def do_row():
    print '+----',
    print '+'



def do_quarter():
    print do_row()
    print do_worms()
    print do_wormsr()
    print do_row()
    print do_worms()
    print do_wormsr()
    print do_row()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any python function that does not have a `return value` will `return None` by default so when you `print do_row()` etc.. you will get `None` after the print output

Not sure what you are printing but you would need to do something along the lines of the following to remove the None from your output:

```
def do_row():
    return '+----+'
```

Comment: note: ideally you would also move more toward the string approach and do concatenation. if you call it with `print do_quarter()`, you decouple the actual output "device".